# math.random giving 2879.95 when spawning enemies

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have this code:

```
for(i = 0; i < mySharedObject.data.randomspawns; i++)
{
    var slobbytwenty  = new Slob();
    slobbytwenty.gotoAndStop(2);
    var Highx:Number = stage.stageWidth + (stage.stageWidth / 2);
    var Lowx:Number = stage.stageWidth - stage.stageWidth - (stage.stageWidth / 2);
    var Highy:Number = stage.stageWidth + (stage.stageWidth / 2);
    var Lowy:Number = stage.stageWidth - stage.stageWidth - (stage.stageWidth / 2);
    slobbytwenty.x = Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+Highx-Lowx))+Lowx;
    slobbytwenty.y = Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+Highy-Lowy))+Lowy;
    addChild(slobbytwenty);
    slobbytwenty.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, shootingwhoop);
    slobbytwenty.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE, movewhoop);
    slobarray.push(slobbytwenty);
}
```

But one array item always gives an X coordinate of 2879.95.  Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am very stupid, I just found I had the following:

```
if(slobbytwenty.x > fencing.sides.width)
            {
                slobbytwenty.x = fencing.sides.width;
            }
            if(slobbytwenty.x < fencing.sides.width - fencing.sides.width)
            {
                slobbytwenty.x = fencing.sides.width;
            }
            if(slobbytwenty.y > fencing.sides.height)
            {
                slobbytwenty.y = fencing.sides.height;
            }
            if(slobbytwenty.y < fencing.sides.height - fencing.width)
            {
                slobbytwenty.x = fencing.sides.width;
            }
```

...and it messed up my game. :P

It turns out that the bounds are incorrect in the conditionals and I didn't need that code anyways.